# grouping and displaying models in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with grouping a list, and then building a model that represents that list and displaying the results in a table within a view. For example:

**List of items ordered**

1. Date
2. CustomerId
3. Location
4. Item
5. Price
6. Quantity

How would I correctly model and display that list in a table if I wanted to group the list by location? And what if I wanted to group the list by two properties, for example, Location and CustomerId?

Here is my model:

```
public class ViewInvoice
{
public string ClientLocation { get; set; }
public List<DetailsGroup> Details { get; set; }

public class DetailsGroup
{
    public List<string> Product { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductSize { get; set; }
    public List<string> PackageType { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public List<int> ItemQuantity { get; set; }
}
}
```

I am trying to display this model in a table within my razor view. Here is that code:

```
@using MyModel.MyTools.Orders.SumOrder
@model SumOrder

@{
ViewBag.Title = "View Invoice";
}

<h2>View Invoice</h2>

<table>
    @foreach(var prod in Model.OCI)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @prod.ClientLocation
            </td>
        </tr>
         foreach (var orderItem in prod.Details)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @orderItem.Product
                </td>
                <td>
                    @orderItem.ItemQuantity
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

The first row in the table displays correctly, which is the name of a city, but in the next row I get this:

System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String] System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]

Can someone explain to me why I can not get the list returned in a readable format, and how to correct this problem?

Here is the code I used to group the list for the ViewInvoice model:

```
public SumOrder(List<orders_Cart> order)
    {
        // create list of order cart item
        List<OrderCartItems> cartItems = new List<OrderCartItems>();

        // convert orders to ocm
        foreach(var item in order)
        {
            var newCartItem = new OrderCartItems();
            try
            {
                newCartItem.Product = db.product_Product.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                    p.Id == item.ProductId).ProductDescription ?? "none";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                newCartItem.Product = "none";
            }
            try
            {
                newCartItem.ClientForProduct = MyTool.OrdersFindClientLocation(
                    (int) item.ClientForOrdersId);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                newCartItem.ClientForProduct = new object[3];
            }
            try
            {
                newCartItem.ProductSize = db.products_Size.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id ==
                    item.ProductSizeId).ProductSizeCode ?? "none";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                newCartItem.ProductSize = "none";
            }
            try
            {
                newCartItem.PackageType = db.packaging_PackageType.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                    p.Id == item.PackageTypeId).PackageTypeCode ?? "none";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                newCartItem.PackageType = "none";
            }
            newCartItem.OrderDate = (DateTime) item.OrderDate;
            newCartItem.DeliveryDate = (DateTime) item.DeliveryDate;
            newCartItem.OrderNumber = (int) item.OrderNumber;
            newCartItem.Price = (decimal) item.Price;
            newCartItem.ClientLocation = MyTool.OrdersFindClientLocation(
                (int) item.ClientForOrdersId, null);
            newCartItem.ItemQuantity = (int) item.Quantity;
            cartItems.Add(newCartItem);
        }

        // group the cartItems according to location
        List<ViewInvoice> ordersGrouped = cartItems.GroupBy(c => new 
            {c.ClientLocation})
            .OrderBy(c => c.Key.ClientLocation).Select(s =>
                new ViewInvoice()
                    {
                        ClientLocation = s.Key.ClientLocation,
                        Details = new List<ViewInvoice.DetailsGroup>()
                            {
                                new ViewInvoice.DetailsGroup()
                                    {
                                        Product = s.Select(p => p.Product).ToList(),
                                        ItemQuantity = s.Select(p => p.ItemQuantity).ToList(),
                                        DeliveryDate = s.Select(p => p.DeliveryDate).ToList(),
                                        OrderDate = s.Select(p => p.OrderDate).ToList(),
                                        OrderNumber = s.Select(p => p.OrderNumber).ToList(),
                                        PackageType = s.Select(p => p.PackageType).ToList(),
                                        Price = s.Select(p => p.Price).ToList(),
                                        ProductSize = s.Select(p => p.ProductSize).ToList()
                                    }

                            }

                    }).ToList();

        // set the OCI property
        OCI = ordersGrouped;
    };
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What difficulties did you encounter with your code when you attempted to solve this? What is your specific question?

Comment: you're missing a level of list, or have one useless. Could you show the structure of CartItem ?

Comment: Ok, I've included the cartItems list.

Comment: Why are you using so many try/catches??  You know you can use a single try/catch and it will work for anything that throws, right?  Edited: Never mind.  I see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved my problem. I initially over-thought the problem. I simplified my model, and added some simple logic to my view.

Here is the updated Model:

```
public class ViewInvoice
{
    public string ClientLocation { get; set; }
    public List<string> Product { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductSize { get; set; }
    public List<string> PackageType { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public List<int> ItemQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

the updated code used to group the list for the Model:

```
// group the cartItems according to location
        List<ViewInvoice> ordersGrouped = cartItems.GroupBy(c => new 
            {c.ClientLocation})
            .OrderBy(c => c.Key.ClientLocation).Select(s =>
                new ViewInvoice()
                    {
                        ClientLocation = s.Key.ClientLocation,
                        Product = s.Select(p => p.Product).ToList(),
                        ItemQuantity = s.Select(p => p.ItemQuantity).ToList(),
                        DeliveryDate = s.Select(p => p.DeliveryDate).ToList(),
                        OrderDate = s.Select(p => p.OrderDate).ToList(),
                        OrderNumber = s.Select(p => p.OrderNumber).ToList(),
                        PackageType = s.Select(p => p.PackageType).ToList(),
                        Price = s.Select(p => p.Price).ToList(),
                        ProductSize = s.Select(p => p.ProductSize).ToList()

                    }).ToList();
```

and the updated view:

```
@using MyModel.MyTools.Orders.SumOrder
@model SumOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Invoice";
}

<h2>View Invoice</h2>
@{
    int i = 0;
}
<table>
    @foreach(var mod in Model.OCI)
    {
        var modCount = @mod.Product.Count();
        <tr>
            <th>@mod.ClientLocation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        foreach (var items in mod.Product)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @mod.Product.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @mod.Price.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
                </td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }

    }
</table>
```

This solution clearly allows me to iterate through the model reproducing any required rows or cells along the way.  Played Russian roulette for two days over this problem. Hope this saves some others some time.